# How to create a SDO_Geometry over Oracle-JDBC

Tags: oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement, geospatial, spatial

I want to create an Oracle Spatial Geometry over JDBC with the following Statement:

```
    //insert vorbereiten
    try {
        preStatement = conn.prepareStatement("insert into way(id, shape) "
                + "values(? ,SDO_GEOMETRY(2002,NULL,NULL,SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,2,1), SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(?)))");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

     try {
     System.out.println("setString:");
     preStatement.setString(1, "1");

     Array a=conn.createArrayOf("double", new Object[]{9.23, 52.45, 9.67, 52.54});
     preStatement.setArray(2,  a);
     } catch (SQLException e) {
     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

But this does not work. Can someone please tell me how I can set the SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(?)-Values ?